# Parallax website and django views

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to apply a parallax template to my django blog but i seem to be running into a snag

```html
class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.BlogPost.objects.published()
    template_name = "blog/blogindex.html"
    paginate_by = 5
```

I have this view in my views for my blog app.

Now the problem is I four divs I want to split this view into and render into the template.

```html
    <section class="module parallax parallax-1">
  <div class="container">
    
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
 {{ view goes here }}
</section>

<section class="module parallax parallax-2">
  <div class="container">
    
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
{{ view goes here }} 
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module parallax parallax-3">
  <div class="container">
    
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
 {{ view goes here }}
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module parallax parallax-4">
  <div class="container">
    
  </div>
```

what would be the best way to render my blog posts in each div?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get the desired effect by taking advantage of the for loop counters.

Django's `{% for %}` template generates custom variables within the loop. These include:

- forloop.counter: The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed)
- forloop.counter0:    The current iteration of the loop (0-indexed)
- forloop.revcounter:  The number of iterations from the end of the loop (1-indexed)
- forloop.revcounter0: The number of iterations from the end of the loop (0-indexed)
- forloop.first:   True if this is the first time through the loop
- forloop.last:    True if this is the last time through the loop
- forloop.parentloop   For nested loops, this is the loop surrounding the current one

(via https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Using your example, you may be able to do something like this

```
{% for object in object_list %}
<section class="module parallax parallax-{{ forloop.counter }}">
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    {{ object }}
  </div>
</section>
{% endfor %}
```